# Query regarding Fscore values for confusion matrix

Tags: data-mining

I'm working with confusion matrix for multi-class classification.Now while calculating F score for it,i'm getting 1.4 as value.How can i justify it or should i consider it as optimal result or what?Help me out!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error somewhere.

The value is bound to the 0:1 range. So your computation is wrong.